# How to check the Paypal account has been verifeid or not

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

How to check the user's Paypal account has been verified or not.

We have used the below link to check the status of Paypal account,
https://www.paypal.com/verified/pal=

But this link is not working now.

So, can you help me how to check the verified status of the Paypal account.

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459047/how-to-check-email-or-mobile-phone-paypal-account-status-using-php-api/29462577#29462577

Answer (score 0):

You could use the getVerifiedStatus API to verify the specific account's status.
However you need to submit your application request to make the API call.
Please refer the [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-accounts/) for adaptive accounts.

The detailed parameters for getVerifiedStatus API can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/).

Answer (score 0):

This link is working in 2018
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_status

You should be logged in first, after that open this link ...

Thanks